# Trivial pretzel links

Tags: knot-theory

Is there a simple rule to check whether a pretzel link P(n_1,...,n_k) is a trivial link?
I am interested in the 2-component case but every information would be helpful.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel_link for those who, like me, didn't know what a pretzel link is. In general one should try to define jargon, or provide link to background material, when asking a question on MO. 

Comment: Why specify to 2-components? Is there an easy way to tell whether a pretzel link has exactly two components? 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pretzel link has as many components as the pretzel link with coefficients reduced $(\mod 2)$. So it will have two components if and only if there are precisely two even coefficients.

A conceptual classification is given by considering the 2-fold branched cover, or the $\pi$-orbifold, obtained by taking the orbifold quotient of the 2-fold branched cover. For pretzel links, the 2-fold branched cover is a connect sum of Seifert fibered spaces (this is more generally true for Montesinos links). Then a 2-component link is trivial if and only if the two-fold branched cover is $S^2\times S^1$. A theorem of [Bonahon and Siebenmann](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=827297) classifies Seifert fibered orbifolds, so in principal you can classify pretzel links from their classification.

Comment: Ah, after you pointed it out in your first paragraph, it is actually completely obvious that it should be so. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I was looking for something like an algorithm but that's interesting.  

Answer (score 1):

In principle, normal surface theory answers your question - it can detect if a link is split and can decide if a knot is unknotted.  In practice, just draw your link in SnapPea.  But neither if these could be called a "simple rule."  You might look at [Purcell's](http://math.byu.edu/~jpurcell/papers.html) thesis work/early papers (eg "Volumes of highly twisted knots and links"), using hyperbolic geometry, to give a simple rule implying that a link is non-trivial.